# it seems me that javascript If...Else works strangely

Tags: javascript, highmaps

I have statement if...else.

```
$.each(mapGeoJSON.features, function (index, feature) {
        if((Overview.countryData[index])!='undefined'){
            data.push({
                key: feature.properties['hc-key'],
                value: Overview.countryData[index].value
            });
        }else{
            data.push({
                key: feature.properties['hc-key'],
                value: 0
            });
        };
    });
```

I have only 1 data in Overview.countryData but it works the second time and gives error Cannot read property 'value' of undefined on line 5. what is the reason Who can say?

Comment: Typo: `(Overview.countryData[index])!='undefined'` should be `typeof Overview.countryData[index] !== 'undefined'`.

Comment: Because your loop is working to the length of `mapGeoJSON.features`. What is the length of `mapGeoJSON.features`

Comment: aaaaaaaaa I have forgotten. Thank you

Comment: Sanchit the length is 212 but the problem is typeof()

Comment: `'undefined'` is not a missing, unset or not yet set value. It is the string literal `'undefined'`. Not the same thing as `undefined` (remark there are no quotes around it). And `undefined != 'undefined'`.

Comment: merci guys very much

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very simple. `Overview.countryData[index]` is not defined for the value of `index` and its value in the `if` condition is `undefined`.

But `undefined` is not the same thing as `'undefined'`.

`undefined` is the value of a missing key in an object or array, the value of a variable that has be unset or not yet set.

`'undefined'` is a string literal.

No matter how do you compare them (using `==` or `===`), `undefined` and `'undefined'` are never equal.
Because of that, the `if` condition is always `true` and it is always taken. But the code in the `if` branch assumes that `Overview.countryData[index]` exists (is defined, is not `undefined`).

The correct test condition is:

```
if (Overview.countryData[index] != undefined)
```

You can use, as well:

```
if (Overview.countryData[index])
```

because `undefined` is always evaluated as `false` in boolean context. The code is more clear this way.

Comment: The more correct way to check if a property exists is `Overview.countryData.hasOwnProperty(index)` or `index in Overview.countryData` for inherited properties. That way you won't get a false negative if the property exists and the value is undefined. I know it's an edge case, just suggesting.q